# Fetch an image based on Screen-Resolution [via HTML Only]

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a recent interview I was asked by the interviewer that you got 2 images:

1. One large resolution image that you have to show on laptops & desktops.
2. One small image that you have to show only on mobiles.

You have to fetch a certain image (1 out of these 2) based on "screen resolution" only by the help of **HTML Only**. You should not do this with help of CSS/JS/jQuery!

Though, my HTML is pretty good, but I could not answer this. Anybody, has any knowledge of what the interviewer meant? or what is the correct Solution?

Comment: picture tag is your friend here

Comment: @AtulRajput - I never got you? I mean what ....

Comment: I have added a detailed answer for the same, Please check, Happy Coding mate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this thing by using `picture` tag. check this example below.

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:600px)" srcset="https://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/08-2018/3-nature-wallpaper-mountain.jpg">
  <img src="https://cdn141.picsart.com/297499064115201.jpg?type=webp&to=crop&r=256" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p14s0jgw/) for better results, just resize the result window.

check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) for more detail.

Comment: The srcset attribute on a <img /> tag may also help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: yeah, that would also work, but as per my knowledge picture tag gives you more flexibility and it makes code more readable

Comment: `picture` tag is awsome you can also add other image types like `webp` to it, its smaller then a jpg or png. And the browser take whats best to use. If the browser does not support webp it will fallback on the jpg or png

Comment: Yep, but code seems to use (min-width:400px) ... something like this ... which seems similar to `media-query` only!

Comment: You are right @Deadpool, but as your interviewer asked not to use CSS, JS, or jQuery. in this approach all you writing is HTML, the media attribute here works like CSS media Query but its standard syntax for Picture tag, you do not need to write the inline Style or external style for this. so For me and as per specifications mentioned this is all HTML.

Answer (score 3):

```
<img srcset="img-480w.jpg 480w,img-800w.jpg 800w" sizes="(max-width:600px)480px,800px" src="img-800w.jpg" alt="image">
```

You indicate with srcset that img-480w intrinsic width is 480px wide, img-800w is 800px wide.

With sizes you indicate that for a screen with a  max width of 600px to use the 480px image and bigger than that to use the 800px image